# wrap div around inline divs inside

Tags: html, css

I have container div and I populate it with other `inline-block` divs based on search results(search by tag and each inline div contains foundings). I want to wrap my container around my inline divs. Currently container is taking up `100%` of screen. I can not set *fixed width* to container as the content is dynamic and might be `1`, might be `5` or more inline divs.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS? I am sure there is, but I am lost in this case a bit.

Thank you in forward for the help.

Comment: Can we see your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess this would work based on your description...

```css
.container {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    /* Important bit... */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightBlue;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">INLINE-BLOCK</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/ofbb2v1o/)

Comment: Hi, that does the trick, but maybe you know the option how to make it centered horizontally as well? :)